# Why wasn't contents visible on SD card? Is there a write buffer?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, reboot, cache

I am using a SMS backup app that stores a local copy in `/sdcard/sms_backup/`. After running the app and making a backup, I connected the phone to the computer, by a USB cable, and nothing was there. I verified using File Manager, that on the phone the folder did have the backup files. I found restarting the phone fixed the issue, and I was able to view them on the computer.

Is there some sort of bufferthat makes it so contents don't get written to the sd card immediately?

Comment: It's not a buffer, it's more like the file index used for MTP to sort out hidden files and other things didn't discover those files yet.